# Running a batch from Java where the cmd prompt goes away

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I was able to use an amalgamation of SO questions to get a line of code that would:

- Run a batch file from within a Java application
- Include an argument located in the same directory as the batch file
- The argument & batch file are in a directory unrelated to the JAR/java app

So I used this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start batchfile.bat argument.js", null, new File( path ));
```

This works well except that it leaves the cmd prompt open after it has finished executing the batch file. I've looked around and it seems like having the /c flag should make it close after running, but for me it has been staying open. I tried removing 'start' but this meant that the cmd prompt never opened up at all.

Is it because I'm combining having an argument and using a different path that it's not causing the cmd prompt to open and then close after completion like most examples on SO?

Comment: Have you tried `start cmd /c ...`.  I'd also consider using a `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime.exec`

Comment: What about `start /WAIT`? I'm not sure whether both `start` *and* `cmd /C` are really necessary...

Comment: `start cmd /c` causes an IOException, using the same commands with `ProcessBuilder` gives me the same issues, `start /WAIT` causes an IOException.
I also didn't think `start` and `cmd /C` were both necessary, but I get no command prompt at all without `start`.

Comment: `cmd /c batchfile.bat argument.js` should work, but if not, a simple cure is end the batch file with `exit` command (not /B switch)

Comment: When you call it and the command line foes not show up, it still runs it in the process. You can read the output from the console using the InputStream.

Answer (score 2):

Calling both `cmd.exe` and `start` in that order is creating a separate window but it doesn't seem like the command shell is terminating based on what you described. I was able to replicate this behavior in a simple batch script. If you want to leave your Java call as it is, check to make sure your batch script includes an `exit` statement. Preferably exit based on a success or failure condition within your batch script (i.e.: `exit 0` or `exit 1`, etc...)

```
:: batchfile.bat
...
exit 0
```

Assuming you are not firing up any new shells within your batch script or prompting for input, adding an explicit exit to your existing batch script should cause the window to close. You can also try to leave your batch script as is, and as others have suggested in comments, change the order of your command text slightly.

**Use this instead**

```
start cmd.exe /c ...
```

Where you call `start` first and then call `cmd.exe /c` after followed by your parameters as needed. I tried both options here and either worked fine to cause the batch window to close as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the below command to Runtime to execute.

> taskkill /F /IM (processName)

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM "+pProcessName);
```